# sed replace AFTER match and retain

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I've been racking my brains for hours on this, but it seems simple enough. I have a large list of strings similar to the ones below and would like to replace the hyphens **only after the comma**, to commas:

```
abc-d-ef,1-2-3-4
gh-ij,1-2-3-4
```

*to this*

```
abc-def,1,2,3,4
gh-ij,1,2,3,4
```

I can't use s/-/,/2g to replace from second occurrence as the data differs, and also though about using cut, but there must be a way to use sed with something like:

```
"s/\(,\).*-/\1,&/g"
```

Thank you

Comment: could your original input have multiple commas?

Comment: @Kent yes original can have multiple commas; I just need it to act after the first comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more suitable for `awk` as we can break all lines using comma as field separator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/-/, OFS, $2)} 1' file

abc-d-ef,1,2,3,4
gh-ij,1,2,3,4
```

If you want `sed` solution only then use:

```
sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/([^,]+,[^-]+)-/\1,/g;ta' file

abc-d-ef,1,2,3,4
gh-ij,1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

An awk proposal.

```
awk -F, '{sub(/d-ef/,"def")gsub(/-/,",",$2)}1' OFS=, file

abc-def,1,2,3,4
gh-ij,1,2,3,4
```